# Verificar se um item específico está selecionado em um dos combos na página

Tags: javascript, asp

Eu tenho uma página em asp classic com diversos combos e todos com nomes diferentes e um botão que salva todos os valores selecionados. Eu preciso verificar no javascript se algum destes combos tem a opção "Cancelado" selecionado e dar uma mensagem de confirmação dizendo que um dos combos tem esta opção selecionada. É preciso mostrar essa confirmação para todos os combos com esta opção selecionada.

A quantidade de combos não é automática. É possível checar todos os combos no javascript antes de dar o submit na página?

Os nomes do combos seguem um padrão "status_anterior_<%=contador %>" iniciando em 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando jQuery, da seguinte forma:

```
function ValidarAcao() {
    var algumItemCancelado = false;

    $('select').each(function(i, e){
        if ($(e).attr("id").indexOf("status_anterior_") > -1 && $(e).val() == "Cancelado") {
            algumItemCancelado = true;
        }
    });

    if (algumItemCancelado){
        return confirm("Existe um ou mais itens com a opção 'cancelado' selecionados. Deseja continuar?");
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Acabei fazendo diversas modificações, mas este código foi a base pra TUDO!